# How to get all Enum Flags from a Number in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, enums

Given: 
Enum: `{1, 4, 16}` 
Flags: 20

When:
I pass Flags to a function

Then:
I get array of flags of given Enum: `[4, 16]`

Note: I have tried to convert Enum to array manually and treat values as numbers. But I get overwhelmed when it gets to TS and I want to make that function dynamic in case Enum gets changed. I really don't want hardcode that. Please help!

```
enum Enum {
    one = 1,
    four = 4,
    sixteen = 16,
}

const Flags: number = 20;

function getEnumValues(flags: number): Enum[] {
    const enumFlags = [1, 4, 16];
    
    const enums: Enum[] = [];

    enumFlags.forEach(ef => {
        if ((ef & flags) != 0) {
            enums.push(ef);
        }
    })

    return enums;
}

console.log(getEnumValues(Flags));
```

Solution found here: [Typescript flagged enum get values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45354289/typescript-flagged-enum-get-values)
Is not good because my Enum is not a sequence 2 and 8 is missing.

Comment: What's the problem with your current solution? It [seems to work](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAou0G8BQVVQPYmFAvFAjADQpoBm6YATrlACzFpQDOAlgB4AuwoN+AbMQC+SJAGNMTDlABiAGwCGAcyYAuKPABGwangBMABgDcI0mBCiOLTFEXAOcSADV5ssMCYAKUguVrN2gEo1BwgAbQBdKGRGcRBJKFBIOSUmGlCiOkICPnDjRhJUWPjEiFVYeAi03JFGEuTlADpyShh5UQALD2BSXAA+KILGKBYejy6egDIobxSAqABCPH056KG1kqYGgAcwJk7ugLy1qGFGQQCatEo7KhAE+CZjYTEJdFlgBtl0RQ9be3hnK53B56kwAocgA)...? The fact that you have the flag numbers in the function?

Comment: Yes, I need to have flags dynamically generated and not hardcoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have encountered a similar challenge in the past. And by coincidence, I have written an article about that, because it was a really interesting challenge.

You can find the link here: https://dev.to/sincovschi/bitwise-enum-flags-to-generate-html-from-array-3576

The first thing you need is a helper that extracts Enum's flags as an array by treating TS `enum` as an ordinary object. After that, your approach is good to go by looping over flags and see if it's present in your number.

Snippet copied from the link above's code sandbox.

```
const isPowerOfTwo = (x: number): boolean => {
  return x != 0 && (x & (x - 1)) == 0;
};

export function getEnumFlags<
  O extends object,
  K extends O[keyof O] = O[keyof O]
>(obj: O): K[] {
  const isFlag = (arg: string | number | K): arg is K => {
    const nArg = Number(arg);
    const isNumber = !Number.isNaN(nArg);
    return isNumber && isPowerOfTwo(nArg);
  };

  const enumFlags: K[] = [];

  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    const nKey = Number(key);
    if (isFlag(nKey)) {
      enumFlags.push(nKey);
    }
  });

  return enumFlags;
}
```

Comment: I like the concept and the way it keeps you safe even if you pass in some values of enums already pre-combined. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If your concern is that you're repeating the `Enum` values in the `enumFlags` array in the function, you can get them dynamically:

```
const enumFlags = Object.values(Enum)
    .filter((value): value is number => typeof value === "number");
```

You need to make the `filter` callback a type guard function (using a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates), `value is number`) because otherwise TypeScript thinks the array is of type `(string | Enum)[]`. But we know it isn't, because we're doing `typeof === "number"`.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=1&pln=10&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBAou0G8BQVVQPYmFAvFAjADQpoBm6YATrlACzFpQDOAlgB4AuwoN+AbMQC+SJAGNMTDlABiAGwCGAcyYAuKPABGwangBMABgDcI0mBCiOLTFEXAOcSADV5ssMCYAKUguVrN2gEo1BwgAbQBdKGRGcRBJKFBIOSUmGgB5DQArYAsAOgA3FzdPEICSRlRc0hZZLkoPD0LXYCCoJrcoFlT-HQA+KA4ATwAHYHRSNqLsHBmoACIeuYDjRnKoWPjEiFVYeAiaCOM1reTlKvRKGHlRAAsPYAmcfuiK1BYJhoeoADIobxSAlAAIR4fSAl6vRhbJi5YZgJh3B7LNaMYSosprSh2KggBLwJjGYRiCToWTAXKydCKDy2ezwZzNTynJgBZZAA)

Since building that array isn't free it may be worth doing that once, just after the `Enum` definition, and reusing it. That said, while it's not free, it's really cheap (and keeping it isn't free either: it occupies [a tiny bit of] memory).

Comment: This seems a very elegant way to solve the issue in a dirty way, TS has some errors in your Playground which I presume may be solved with casts.

Comment: @MimeMute - That's embarrassing, I missed the errors as I was on the Logs tab and being clueless. I would never usually post an answer with errors without saying something about them. Sorry about that!

Comment: @MimeMute - Turns out it wanted one type assertion. I'm fairly leery of type assertions generally, but this one seems reasonable and isn't so egregious it requires `as unknown` first. :-)

Comment: Sorry for undeleting (I thought it is just vote). You could use type predicate `Object.values(Enum).filter((value): value is number => typeof value === "number")` to help typescript to understand that resulting array will have only numbers

Comment: @AlekseyL. I undeleted it when I added the type predicate. A type guard annotation is a great idea! I've edited that in.

Comment: I like the type predicate. Its a new trick for me with TS. Thanks.

Comment: @MimeMute - Details: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates

Comment: (In my comment above, I meant I undeleted it when I added the type *assertion*. Later changed it to a type predicate because of @Aleksey's excellent suggestion.)